# How can I start a loop from middle of the array?

Tags: c++

There is a given pseudo code.

```
int Function(X : array[P..Q] of integer)
  
1 maxSoFar = 0
  
2 for L = P to Q
```

I was using C and trying to change it into C++ code.

The reason that I am struggling with it is I have no idea how to express it is start from 'P' in the loop.
I do not know how to do that before initilization even without parameter.

```
 int  Function(vector<int> X)
 {
   int maxSoFar = 0;
   for (int I = 0; I < X.size(); I++) ;
 }
```

This is what I did.
I wonder if it is same with the pseudo code or not.

Comment: How do you do iteration on an array in C++ normally? Is there any part of that that might be able to be changed to alter the starting point?

Comment: If you're trying to translate pseudocode to C++ but you're not sure how to stop a loop, why not start with writing what you _do_ know (say, writing a loop that doesn't break early), then modify it after that's working to solve the early-stop problem. It seems a bit premature otherwise since you haven't written any C++ here yet, so the problem is out of reach.

Comment: I'll add some part of C++ coding but I am not sure if it is same with the pseudo code or not.

Comment: 저의 대답 보세요 There are many other ways with iterators as well, you can google it

Answer (score 1):

You can just divide your vector size by 2:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int  f(vector<int> v) {
    int maxSoFar = 0;
    int len = v.size();
    for (int i = len / 2; i < len; i++) { // i = len / 2, starts from the middle
        maxSoFar += v[i];
        cout << v[i] << ' ';
        cout << maxSoFar << endl;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    vector<int> v = {1, 3, 5};
    f(v);
}
```

output:

```
3 3
5 8
```

You should take a closer look at the [for loop on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop): `for (initialization; break condition; incrementation)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,n;
    cout<<"enter the number of elements : ";
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    cout<<endl<<"enter the value of this array : ";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    cout<<endl<<"print the last half elements of this array : ";
    for(i=(n/2);i<n;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Output: enter the number of elements : 4

enter the value of this array : 1 3 5 7

print the last half elements of this array : 5 7

Comment: You can add the output by editing your answer rather than add same comment.